# Having trouble understanding DBMS Query I/O cost calculation

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization

[image]

Can someone please explain how they worked out the total IO cost in both queries?

Comment: Do you want to know how they got the data from [the execution plan](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1873/how-to-read-sql-server-graphical-query-execution-plans/) or how SQL server itself calculates the value?

Comment: the data from the execution plan. Like how they figured out each IO cost.

Comment: SQL Server figures out the cost for you when you run the execution plan. The people who created the image just put in a pretty picture. Have you tried running a query with the execution plan option on? It will be more clear if you see it with your eyes.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: The usual SQL on oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it.

`I\O Cost` is coming from whatever number of rows you are having to currently do work on.

**PLAN A**:

You `select` all of Product and all of Vendor. That is 7300 rows you have to do work on. But this example will also `join` which means **each** vendor will have all products, so then it `select`s 300 * 7000 = 2100000.

You then have to do work on 2100000 rows to start your vendor code filter.

You then have to do work on 7000 rows to start your state filter since you previously filtered down to your initial product list.

**PLAN B**:
There's a typo, no closing parenthesis for `IN()`.

You for your `IN` first since your query needs that dataset to complete. You know you have 300 vendors so you are doing work on 300 vendors to filter it down to 10.

You then `select` all of your products and all of your florida vendors so you are working with 7010 rows, 7000 products, 10 vendors (from the previous step), so that you can perform the `join` which gives each vendor 7000 products.

10 * 7000 means you are now working with 70000 rows to perform the final filter on `v_code`.

**Total I\O Cost** is the sum for each processing step.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood what you were saying up until the point of the why we got 7010 IO cost. Can you please elaborate on that part? Ty

Comment: Thanks fam, i appreciate it.